# Extending Visa type or applying again for standard Visa C type(UK)

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

Good day
I have MUlt C type standard visa uk for 6 months from April 18 till 05th Oct 18.
I am studying in Sweden.Meanwhile for attending in a UN conference on behalf of my university it needs i go to UK on 13th OCT(8 days after expiry of my visa date).
Please advise what should apply for visa
1-Apply new application for standard visa again?or
2-Apply to extend the present visa.(As i read in UK.GOV site for Uk visa extension i should be present in UK,However i am in Sweden now).
Kindly Advise.
Best Regards

Comment: Not sure why you needed to ask this question since you’d already found the explicit answer on the UK visa website.

Answer (score 2):

It only makes sense to extend your stay in the UK if you are already in the UK.

If you are not in the UK, therefore, you should apply for a new Standard Visitor visa. You do not need to have your existing visa cancelled or changed.

Answer (score 1):

You already have your answer. To apply for a visa extension you must be in the UK. You're in Sweden (which isn't in the UK as far as I'm aware), so you apply for a new visa.